# HStack with images expanding beyond screen

Tags: ios, swiftui, hstack

I'm trying to implement a view that has a subview that just renders an array of images. The number of images to draw varies.

This is my main view:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        if !routeTrips.isEmpty {
            ForEach(routeTrips, id: \.self) { trip in
                Group {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.handleRouteTripTap(routeTrip: trip)
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Image("bus")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .renderingMode(.template)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    .frame(width:30, height: 30)
                                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(trip.LineToShow)")
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    Text("\(trip.Name)")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Text("\(trip.ArrivalTimeToShow)")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            HStack{
                                if nil != trip.SubTrips {
                                    ChangesRow(subTrips: trip.SubTrips ?? [])
                                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                                }
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                if 0 < trip.Price {
                                    Text("\(trip.Price)€")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, opacity: 1))
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                }
            }
        } else {
            Text("Sem viagens")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .listRowBackground(Color(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, opacity: 1))
        }
    }
}
```

The `ChangesRow` is the view that draws one row with images and is implemented as follows:

```
var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(subTrips.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                if subTrips[i].IsWalking {
                    Image("walking")
                        .resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                } else {
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Image("A" == subTrips[i].Provider ? "subway" : "B" == subTrips[i].Provider ? "train" : "bus")
                            .resizable()
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        Image("logo_\(subTrips[i].Provider)")
                            .resizable()
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    }
                }
                
                if(self.subTrips.count - 1 != i) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that If there are many images to draw, the view expands beyond the screen and gets all wonky. Any idea on how I can guarantee that despite the number of images, it will always be drawn visibly?

Where I render the `Price`, I've tried writing a long text, and the view adjusts accordingly. Why doesn't it do the same with the images?

Thanks!

Comment: How many images do you show in a row?

Comment: @Asperi it depends. It's dynamic. Dependent on what the server returns.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the issue or create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @nicksarno I just added a print. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just set the .frame of the HStacks?

Comment: Seing that I want the image minimum size to be either 20/20 or 15/15, and the number of images varies, I don't think so.
I implemented a ScrollView as an workaround.

Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering how this was solved, it wasn't.
I could not set the frame width because the number of images to draw could vary, and I wanted the images frame to be either 20/20 or 15/15.

I was able to achieve an acceptable result by implementing a `ScrollView` that only scrolls horizontally.